# Joining declaration and initialization vs initializing in init block

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

Is there a difference between this two ways of initializing a custom view?

**Option 1(on init block)**

```
class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null)
    : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {


    private val myCustomView: LinearLayout

    init {
        myCustomView = inflate(context, R.layout.buff_view, this) as LinearLayout
    }

    fun start() {
        getPosts()
    }
...
}
```

**Option 2(no init block)**

```
class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null)
    : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {


    private val myCustomView = inflate(context, R.layout.buff_view, this) as LinearLayout

    fun start() {
        getPosts()
    }
...
}
```

If I use the option 1, the custom view variable shows me a warning that says it can be joined with assignment, unless I declare it as nullable. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors):

> During an instance initialization, the initializer blocks are executed in the same order as they appear in the class body, interleaved with the property initializers

That means that property initialization and init block execute in a top-down manner.

To answer your question, in Option 1 you are declaring the variable and then you initialize it and in Option 2 you are joining the declaration and initialization.

The following example will result in the same scenario:

```kotlin
fun start() {
    val test: String
    test = "demo"

    getPosts()
}
```

So you might as well write:

```kotlin
fun start() {
    val test = "demo"

    getPosts()
}
```

The [Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint) check is not showing you a warning. It is giving you the information that you might as well join the declaration and initialization. So there will be no consequence if you continue to use Option 1.